# Apache VirtualHost configure

Tags: apache, virtualhost

After I configured virtual host, my apache document root changed to the virtual host's document root, I just want to know why.

here is my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName myapp.zend 
   DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/php_zend_projects/myapp
   <Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/php_zend_projects/myapp/public> 
      DirectoryIndex index.php 
      AllowOverride All 
      Order allow,deny 
      Allow from all 
      <IfModule mod_authz_core.c> 
         Require all granted 
      </IfModule> 
   </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

After I restart apache server, localhost page changed to index of `/opt/lampp/htdocs/php_zend_projects/myapp`,

http://gwjyhs.com/t6/702/1556725814x2728329017.png

but it is supposed to be xampp's default page like this:

http://gwjyhs.com/t6/702/1556726269x2728278877.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable vhosts you have to add an entry that looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:/Dev/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

*Note: change path to whatever is appropriate for you.*

Restart webserver and it should work as before.

Reasoning behind this can be found in a comment on top of the `httpd-vhosts.conf`:

> The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any  block.

That means when you type in `localhost` it fallbacks to your `myapp.zend` vhost because it is (probably) the first virtualhost section.

Comment: OK, understand, it seems that I need to configure another vhost for lampp

Comment: @anonymous If my answer helped you, you should accept it so others can find it and get help too.